# Safari (iOS and OSX) doesn't display position: absolute inside flexbox

Tags: css, safari

I have a project, where I am using `position: absolute` to place names on a leaderboard. This is inside a div which has `scroll: auto` and is also a flexbox (from Bootstrap). This works fine on Chrome, however trying to use this on Safari ends up with the names simply not appearing.

I have a JS fiddle of a simplified version here: https://jsfiddle.net/gfbu0aez/4/

If you open it in Chrome, the numbers appear just fine, but opening it in Safari results in nothing appearing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `height: 100%;` from your `.container` class, as `flex-grow: 1;` already does what you need.

See [this question / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33636796/chrome-safari-not-filling-100-height-of-flex-parent) for more details.

Comment: You live saver! IOS 14.4 .... what a blessing to have Safari be the new Internet Explorer. But glad the community is always able to help. Thanks!